# Elastic Beanstalk service role not granted permission from additional Policy attached

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am using AWS secrets manager and have created a policy permitting programmatic access to a certain set of secrets. I created a new user and attached that and only that policy to the user, and am able to interact with the secrets perfectly.

Inside Elastic Beanstalk I tested this by manually setting the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as environment variables on the Elastic Beanstalk. When running via this method everything works great. I don't want to expose the secret access key to any developer with access the console so I want instead to attach that policy to the Elastic Beanstalk service role

So I created a new elastic beanstalk service role for my application, attached my the same policy, and then set EB to use that new service role, per below details.

[image: EB setting]

[image: IAM setting]

Since it works great when I set the environment vars on EB for aws keys, but doens't work when I attach to the service role, I must assume it's not related to my policy, but just in case here is the full policy details.

I'm not sure what I could be missing? Is it related to the Virtual Machine permissions? Or did I somehow configure my policy incorrectly?

Service role details contains the two managed policies from AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth and AWSElasticBeanstalkService plus my custom role for pre-prod access

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
            "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
            "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:ASDFG",
            "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:QWERT"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
            "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role is fully default and looks like this

[image: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it was the Virtual Machine permissions. I just created a new service role, copied the policies from aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role, added my custom policy for secrets manager, and then set the Virtual Machine IAM instance profile to use that new role, et voila!

Comment: Seems like the role permission changes are not applied immediately to the EC2 instances in the Elastic Beanstalk. When the role of the VM instance is changed, all EC2 instances are restarted and it solves the issue.